# Streaming Results from Mochiweb

Tags: erlang, mochiweb

I have written a web-service using Erlang and Mochiweb. The web service returns a lot of results and takes some time to finish the computation.
I'd like to return results as soon as the program finds it, instead of returning them when it found them all.

edit:

i found that i can use a chunked request to stream result, but seems that i can't find a way to close the connection. so any idea on how to close a mochiweb request?

Comment: SO ist not chat, the questions and answers are here to stay for reference forever. Please spend a bit more work formulating your questions.  You can however save time by leaving out the "my problem is simple" and preemptive "thanks" (thanks would be more appropriate as comment to good answers)

Comment: well i think the problem is easy enough for someone who really know how mochiweb works, and i accepted all the answer that were really right answer to the problem i submit. i dont ask opinions, the problem is simple, i need a simple solution.

Comment: Just wanted to be of help with some experience which form of questions get more answers and which not.  Avoidance of clutter like this is the approved way of asking, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stream data of yet unknown size with HTTP 1.1 you can use [HTPP chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). In this encoding each chunk of data prepended by its size in hexadecimal. Last chunk is a zero-length chunk, with the chunk size coded as 0, but without any data.

If client doesn't support HTTP 1.1 server can send data as binary chunks and close connection at the end of the stream.

In [MochiWeb](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb) it's all works as following:

1. HTTP response should be started with `Response = Request:`[respond({Code, ResponseHeaders, chunked})](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiweb_request.erl#L300) function. (By the way, look at the code comments);
2. Then chunks can be send to client with `Response:`[write_chunk(Data)](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiweb_response.erl#L49) function. To indicate client the end of the stream chunk of zero length should be sent: `Response:write_chunk(<<>>)`.
3. When handling of current request is over MochiWeb decides should connection be closed or can be reused by [HTTP persistent connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).